# Linting `import.meta.env` expressions in svelte+vite app

Tags: eslint, vite, svelte

I have a primitive svelte app, which is built with Vite. I'm using Vite's way to access env vars, like this:

```
<div class="app">
  {import.meta.env.VITE_WHATEVER}
</div>
```

I works and show my var as expected.

Now I want to add eslint to my app. So I installed `eslint-plugin-svelte` and added following to eslintrc:

```
{
  overrides: [
    {
       files: [ '*.svelte' ],
       extends: [ 'plugin:svelte/recommended' ]
    }
  ]
}
```

With that, eslint gives `Parsing error: Unexpected token import` error.

What do I do to make eslint recognize this expression properly?